# How do I get two fonts on the same line in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

So here is the deal, I am trying to get a certain look on my page but I'm not getting cooperation from Wordpress. I want an h4 followed by paragraph text that is in italics (also indented). This is the code I'm using and it works fine in my editor:

```
<h4 style="padding-left: 30px; display:inline;">Culture of Radical-Devotion</h4> <p style="display:inline;">“they devoted themselves”</p>
```

However, when I view the code in Wordpress it is on separate lines. The page you can view this at is http://clients.gadietrich.com/gccne/about/our-culture/.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off Wordpress' automatic paragraphs by adding this line either in your `functions.php` file, on in the template that shouldn't use this filter.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

If this solution doesn't suit you, you can try replacing `</h4> <p` with `</h4>&nbsp;<p`.

Comment: The functions.php method does indeed work, however, it strips out all paragraphs from the whole site, which just isn't best for me. I tried the other method as well and that didn't work...and frankly doesn't make sense to me on why I would want to add a line between those elements.

Comment: What if you just remove the space between the tags? And add it _inside_ one of the tags.

Comment: That's the stuff right there! I put the &nbsp; inside at the end of the <p> tag and it is now right. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with wordpress but if this could help: Wordpress (or something else)puts this`<p>&nbsp;
</p>` between the two texts. This is an empty paragraph (a space in it). You just need to remove it somehow

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra paragraph between the heading and paragraph

```
<p>&nbsp;
</p>
```

Remove this and it will work as desired

Comment: But this doesn't exist in my original code. Wordpress is adding this somehow.

Comment: I assume you are using the rich text editor provided by wordpress? If so you should be able to switch to a raw view mode and ensure that the RTE doesnt add this extra space. Theres other options if you can assign classes to the paragraph and h4, let me know  if you need more details

Comment: I pretty much use the html editor exclusively...and that <p> is not in there at all. It is happening somehow either through the theme (which a friend coded) or through Wordpress directly.

Comment: Can you add a class to the h4? If so do that then use some css to target a p tag following that specific heading and set it to display none

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't *wrong*, but if I check out your website I see a little additional extra:

```
<h4 style="padding-left: 30px; display:inline;">Culture of Radical-Devotion</h4>
<p>  </p>
<p style="display:inline;">“they devoted themselves”</p>
```

The paragraph between the two elements you are working with is a block element, so takes up the entire line.

Remove the additional paragraph and you'll be closer.

Comment: I believe that there is a setting / plug-in for WP that remove the extra `<p>`tags that WP adds.

Comment: Well that is the thing, Wordpress is adding those extra <p> tags in there.